# Is it possible to serve mobile apps with ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an old Web Application (Web Site) which has been implemented using ASP.NET Web Forms.

The Web Site is working fine. I want to have its mobile app (Android & IOS) as well.

Is that possible since the web site has been done with ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: If i assume that your services layer is managed separately, then you can develop API easily. and yes possible.

Comment: There is no separation of concerns. Unfortunately, UI and business are tightly coupled. If I can separate the services layer, should it be implemented using Web API? I want to serve the apps using JSON format?

Comment: *should it be implemented using Web API* Yes, *I want to serve the apps using JSON format?* WebApi supports an other format as well, but it's good use Json, that will make your work more easier.

Comment: I got it, thanks @Div

Comment: Please accept this as an answer if it's helpful [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

If i assume that your services layer is managed separately, then you can develop API easily. And yes it's possible.

> There is no separation of concerns. Unfortunately, UI and business are
>   tightly coupled

So, you can separate it, and call service layer methods from your WebApi. It supports an other format as well, but it's good use JSON, that will make your work more easier.

You can refer this document: [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Hope this helps!